# When running the Spring application on EC2, accessing /resources/docs/index.html results in a 401 error

Tags: spring, amazon-ec2

When running the Spring application on EC2, accessing /resources/docs/index.html results in a 401 error. However, there are no issues accessing static resource files when running locally. What could be the problem?

Here is the Spring Security configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final String[] WHITE_LIST = {"/test", "/resources/**", "/images", "/docs/**", "/static/**", "/greeting", "/favicon.ico", "/*/icon-*", "/css/**", "/js/**"};
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    private final JwtAccessDeniedHandler jwtAccessDeniedHandler;
    private final AuthenticationTokenExceptionHandler authenticationTokenExceptionHandler;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(c -> c.configurationSource(request -> {
                    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://server.myhost.com", "http://localhost:8080"));
                    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
                    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                    configuration.setMaxAge(3600L); //1시간
                    return configuration;
                }))
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(d -> d.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))              .authorizeHttpRequests(matchers -> matchers
                        .requestMatchers(WHITE_LIST)
                        .permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, ACCOUNTS_ROOT_PATH, LOGIN_PATH, RE_ISSUE_PATH, LOGOUT_PATH)
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())

                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenExceptionHandler, JwtAuthenticationFilter.class)

                .exceptionHandling(
                        handle -> handle
                                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                                .accessDeniedHandler(jwtAccessDeniedHandler)
                )
                .build();
    }
}
```

n the deployment environment, upon checking, the static resource files were not found.